# Widgetpack Star ratings on my blog do not pass to google

Tags: javascript, seo, google-search-console, rating

I am using Widget Pack Star Rating on my website blogs. But when I search my blog from Google it did not show those star ratings on google search page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    wpac_init = window.wpac_init || [];
    wpac_init.push({
    widget: 'Rating',
    id: ####,
    el: 'wpac-rating-custom',
    html: '{{=it.stars}} {{?it.count>0}} {{=it.rating}} ({{=it.count}} {{=it.votes}}){{?}}'
    });
   (function() {
   if ('WIDGETPACK_LOADED' in window) return;
   WIDGETPACK_LOADED = true;
   var mc = document.createElement('script');
   mc.type = 'text/javascript';
   mc.async = true;
   mc.src = '//embed.widgetpack.com/widget.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(mc, s.nextSibling);
   })();
</script>
```